# How's the memory allocated for multidimensional array when one of the index is not specified

Tags: java, arrays, memory

Let's say I have a Java Program

```
int[5][] array;
arr[0]= getMeArray(var);
arr[1]= getMeArray(var);
..and so on

public int[] getMeArray(int var){
 if(var == 0)
  return new int[9];
 else
  return new int[5];
}
```

Now, is the memory allocation done on compile time, because it should be done as per my understanding, but I am not sure how to figure out how much should be allocated to array.

Comment: Do you mean in this specific case or in general?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume you meant to write something like:

```
int[][] array = new int[5][];  // this compiles
```

Now, to answer your question: The variable `array` is just a reference; the memory is consumed by whatever it *points* to. In this case, it points to an array of `int[]`s. Specifically, it points to an array of references, each of which points to an `int[]`:

```
                  +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
array ----------> | [0] | [1] | [2] | [3] | [4] |
                  +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
                     |     |     |     |     |
                     |     |     |     |     |
                     |     |     |     |     |
                     v     v     v     v     v
                  +-----+ ...   ...   ...   ...
                  |  0  | 
                  +-----+
                  |  0  |   
                    ...
```

The horizontal array is first allocated with `new int[5][]` (which consumes memory). Then, as you allocate each individual integer array in `getMeArray()`, memory is consumed further. This is a **runtime** phenomenon.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, is the memory allocation done on compile time, because it should be done as per my understanding

No, that's how it works in C. Java arrays are completely different!

> but I am not sure how to figure out how much should be allocated to array.

You mean how much memory will be allocated to the array?

A multidimensional array is an array of references to array objects.

A reference to an object takes up a fixed amount of space, let's say B bytes. An `int` array takes approximately 4 bytes per integer, plus an additional 4 bytes for storing its size (as is the case for all Java arrays). So for your example it will be `5*B + 4 +` 4 times the size of each sub-array + 4, for each sub-array. The sub-arrays are only allocated when actually created by your program. This is true for all arrays, they are only allocated when created by your program. My calculation assumes that the whole thing, including the sub-arrays, has already been created.

Answer (score 1):

Java array declarations are nothing but references. So `int[5][] array` won't compile. You can only declare a two dimensional array like `int[][] array` so it'll show that `array` is a reference to 2 dimensional array.
The sizes of arrays are determined in runtime, not in compile time. So it's possible to write a code like this:

```
public void main() {
    int[][] test = new int[get()][];
}
int get() {
    return (int) (Math.random() * 10);
}
```

Even if you declare the size like `int[][] array = new int[5][]`, the size of the `array` won't be determined before the runtime. This also explains why there is no operator like `sizeof` in Java and does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, that program won't work. You need to change this line:

```
int[5][] array;
```

to:

```
int[][] array = new int[5][];
```

All array allocation happens at run time. This will allocate an array of `int[]` arrays (actually, an array of references), all initially set to `null`. Java simply does not have multi-dimensional arrays in the sense of a single block of memory indexed by multiple subscripts. Rather it just has arrays of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Two dimentional aray is an array of arrays. The first array contains referenceg to other arrays. So, memory required to store n refetencies iss allocated.

Theemory for the arrrays of second dimention is allocated later, when methid `getmeArrray` is called.